# Why can not I load a valid url from a pdf in <object> tag using angular?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to embed a pdf on my page using angular. I'm using the `<objetct>` tag to do it. Basically I have 2 buttons, each button refreshes the url of the `<object>` but does not load any. Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

```
<object *ngIf="pdf" [data]="pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
 <p><b>Example fallback content</b>: This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: 
 <a href=".pdf">Download PDF</a>.</p>
</object>

<button (click)="loadPdf1()">Load Pdf 1</button>
<button (click)="loadPdf1()">Load Pdf 2</button>

loadPdf1(){
  this.pdf="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
}
loadPdf2(){
  this.pdf="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"
}
```

this is my full code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cygjuj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: See also forked stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-19b9ne?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @yurzui hey thanks genious! but this not works on firefox.. is incredible :(

Comment: I tried in firefox my link above and it actually works for me

Comment: @yurzui https://imgur.com/9dAZZRU

Comment: I used Firefox 65.0.2

Comment: @yurzui me too.. :O

Comment: What pdf url are you trying? It should start with `https`

Comment: both of them. would this work for pdfs that are stored on my computer?

Comment: It depends on from what is the host you're trying to explore from.

Comment: You always can find all the problems if you open console.